# checking if rxjs observable is complete

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a class that when instantiated makes some web service calls, pseudo code below:

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users'))
 .flatMap(function () {
   return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users'));  
 });
```

The same class is listening for an onclick event.

When this even is triggered, if the original web service calls are complete: do something

If they are *not* complete, wait for them to complete, before doing something.

I was wondering how to achieve this with the rxjs approach? rather than setting variables and using if statements.

Comment: Can you please specify a marble diagram of the intended behaviour? Examples of marble diagrams here ; rxmarbles.com. That basically presenting the inputs and the expected outputs on a timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to this as an Asynchronous Gate. 
These are actually pretty easy to do with Rx. 
You will need to cache the web service calls observable sequences. 
Then in other calls that are predicated on these being complete, you simply `flatMap` off their results.
As these are from Promises I believe the result is retained for late subscribers, but if not then you just need to `replay(1)` the sequences.

So in psudeo code

```
var startUpData = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users'))
 .flatMap(function () {
   return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users'));  
 });

var events = Rx.Observable....//Your event wired up here.

//When an event
events
    .flatMap(function(evt){ 
        //Wait until the startUpData yeilds, but pass on the evt data instead.
        return startUpData.map(function(){ return evt;})
//do something here knowing that your event has fired, but the web services have also completed.
    .subscribe();
```

You can see Matt Barrett explain an Async gate in this video at about 51minutes in to this video - https://youtu.be/Tp5mRlHwZ7M?t=51m30s

You may also want to consider the `switch` operator incase you don't want overlapping events

Answer (score 0):

I believe `withLatestFrom` or `combineLatest` will do what you're asking.

Depending on if you wish to only allow the button to be clicked once with the data provided from the service you could use `withLatestFrom`. If you wish to allow the button to continued to be clicked using the data previously provided by the service you can use `combineLatest`

```
const futureEvent$ = Rx.Observable.timer(3000);
const btnClick$ = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document.querySelector('button'), 'click');
const futureAndBtnClick$ = futureEvent$.combineLatest(btnClick$);

futureAndBtnClick$.subscribe(x => console.log('click + future stuff happened'));
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/xojuqujomu/1/edit?js,console,output)